# Drop-down for discount calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried to get `gross total` value from `discount` calculation to `sub total` value.

Below is my code:

**HTML/PHP**

```
<select class="select" id="discount" onchange="discountedGrossTotal()">
 <option selected>0</option>
 <option value=".02">2</option>
 <option value=".03">3</option>
 <option value=".04">4</option>
</select> </td>

<input name="txtGrossTotal" type="text" id="txtGrossTotal" size="15" readonly/>

<input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" id="txtSubTotal" size="15" value="<?php $sql=mysqli_query($connection,'select sum(amount) from sales_temp');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row[0]; ?>"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function discountedGrossTotal(){
var discountOption = document.getElementById("discount"),
subTotal = document.getElementById("txtSubTotal"),
grossTotal = document.getElementById("txtGrossTotal");

discountOption.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
grossTotal.value = subTotal - subTotal * this[this.selectedIndex].value;
});
}
```

When selects the first option of the drop down, it displays nothing in the `Gross Total` text box. From then, it displays as "NaN" in the text box, whatever option selects.

[image]

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function discountedGrossTotal(dropdownVal){
 var discountOption = document.getElementById("discount"),
 subTotal = document.getElementById("txtSubTotal"),
 grossTotal = document.getElementById("txtGrossTotal");
 grossTotal.value = subTotal.value - (subTotal.value * dropdownVal);

}
```

```html
<select class="select" id="discount" onchange="discountedGrossTotal(this.value)">
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <option value=".02">2</option>
 <option value=".03">3</option>
 <option value=".04">4</option>
</select> 

<input name="txtGrossTotal" type="text" id="txtGrossTotal" size="15" value="" readonly/>

<input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" id="txtSubTotal" size="15" value="200"/>
```

Comment: Oh thanks friend. discounted value calculates now. But, still having the other issue. It displays only from the second click/ select. When first time selects, nothing displays.

Comment: check edited code its working on first time select also. :) @EKBG

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. It works perfectly now. +1 for the simplicity of the code and for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**I would suggest either way to do this:**

**HTML/PHP**

```
<select class="select" id="discount">
 <option selected>0</option>
 <option value=".02">2</option>
 <option value=".03">3</option>
 <option value=".04">4</option>
</select> </td>

<input name="txtGrossTotal" type="text" id="txtGrossTotal" size="15" readonly/>

<input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" id="txtSubTotal" size="15" value="<?php $sql=mysqli_query($connection,'select sum(amount) from sales_temp');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row[0]; ?>"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
var discountOption = document.getElementById("discount");

discountOption.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

var dropdownVal = document.getElementById("discount").value;;
var subTotal = document.getElementById("txtSubTotal").value;
var grossTotal = document.getElementById("txtGrossTotal").value;

grossTotal.value = (subTotal) - (subTotal * dropdownVal);

});
}
```

Comment: yes this also other way to achieve it through addEventListener.

Comment: Thanks @Barney Stinson